# What does it mean when Average Precision is higher than ROC AUC?

Tags: regression

I am using Logistic regression and when I use this model on my validation dataset, I get an AUC ROC of about 0.65 but my Average Precision score is 0.69. How can this be possible? What does it mean?

Comment: I would provide a lot more information about your data, the regression fit, etc if you want reliable advice.

Comment: Hi, my data is about 33000 entries and 39 features. The labels are the same with 33000 entries. It is a binary classification problem. I am trying to implement various models such as Random Forest, XGBoost, Gradient Boosted Trees and Decision Trees.